# Woocommerce webhook not called when creationg an order programatically

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have created an order using this code. An order is successfully created in the order section of the backend but the webhook is not called.

```
$address = array(
            'first_name' => 'Fresher',
            'last_name'  => 'StAcK OvErFloW',
            'company'    => 'stackoverflow',
            'email'      => 'test@test.com',
            'phone'      => '777-777-777-777',
            'address_1'  => '31 Main Street',
            'address_2'  => '', 
            'city'       => 'Chennai',
            'state'      => 'TN',
            'postcode'   => '12345',
            'country'    => 'IN'
        );

        $order = wc_create_order();
        $order->add_product( get_product( '12' ), 2 ); //(get_product with id and next is for quantity)
        $order->set_address( $address, 'billing' );
        $order->set_address( $address, 'shipping' );
        $order->calculate_totals();
```

When I create an order normally the delivery URL is pinged successfully and i can see it in the log too.

Any idea how to get the webhook called?

Comment: Show us the hook code.

Comment: I have added a webhook, like this https://docs.woothemes.com/document/webhooks/

Comment: the above code i posted does not create an order email nor does it fire the webhook

Answer (score 0):

You can manually trigger a hook with [`do_action()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_action):

```
do_action( 'some_wc_hook' );
```

Comment: hi mate, this does not do the trick...it does not send any mail either. I tried this hook   do_action( 'woocommerce_new_order', $order_id );